# How to set static ip in CentOS Stream 9?

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface

I installed a new version CentOS on my hypervisor and I saw that `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*` doesn't exist. In 8 version I set for example `bootproto=static` and `ipaddr=192.168.88.101.`
How correct set static IP in 9 version?

Comment: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go straight for

```bsh
## get a listing of network interfaces
nmcli device
# list here.. say, there's an enp3s0
#
alias cm="nmcli connection modify"
cm enp3s0 ipv4.addresses 192.168.88.101/24
#cm enp3s0 ipv4.gateway, .dns, ...
cm enp3s0 ipv4.method manual
# apply these settings right away!
nmcli connection down enp3s0 ; nmcli connection up enp3s0
```

if I'm using `systemd`'s `NetworkManager` (which you seem to intend to do!).

If using `systemd-networkd`, which might be the right way especially for servers, make the directory `/etc/systemd/network`, and place the configurations (e.g a file `20-wired.network` for your network interfaces there. The [arch Linux wiki has more examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd), but here's from the `man systemd.network` page:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/50-static.network
[Match]
Name=enp2s0

[Network]
Address=192.168.88.101/24
Gateway=192.168.88.1
# DNS=10.1.10.1
```

You'd have to `systemctl disable --now NetworkManager; systemctl enable --now systemd-networkd`, probably.

Comment: Thanks for help, but CentOS doesn't have systemd-networkd https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1650342#c1

Comment: so, go for the `nmcli` solution I gave you!

Comment: While RHEL 8 and 9 (and thus CentOS Stream 8 and 9) don't provide `systemd-networkd` anymore, EPEL 8 and 9 still do.

Comment: Just a confirmation for future people getting here: `nmcli` worked for me on a fresh CentOS 9 Stream install. I did also have to set `ipv4.gateway` and `ipv4.dns`